# Haiku about Movies: We are engaged / Year after year / Year after year

Tags: movies, haiku

What movies are described by the haiku below?

1

> We are engaged
>   Year after year
>   Year after year

2

> No memory of you
>   Every day is the same
>   Every date is different

3

> Stuck at one place
>   for 5.29 days
>   Delusions aplenty

4

> Something bad happened
>   Three of us stuck inside pod
>   Can we still go home?

5

> I am a lawyer with
>   A demanding boss
>   I quit

6

> A secret hobby
>   Of a handsome guy
>   I like, or do I?

7

> A taxi driver
>   A girl comes through the roof
>   Let's find us some stones

8

> A dangerous outlaw
>   A poor guy
>   An afternoon train

9

> Boy writes greeting cards
>   Boy meets girl
>   Boy does not get girl

10

> Catches a psychopath
>   Who catches a plane
>   That catches the passenger who saves the plane

This puzzle has a little theme running through it.

Comment: The "little theme" is numbers in the movie titles?

Comment: Is no-one else going to complain about the lack of 5-7-5 format for the haiku?

Comment: A poem in three lines is not automagically a haiku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the list is complete now, though uncertain on the last answer.

THEME:

> All move titles have numbers in them.

1

> [The Five-Year Engagement](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1195478/)

2

> [50 First Dates](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343660/)

3

> [127 Hours](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1542344/)

4

> [Apollo 13](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/)

5

> [Two Weeks Notice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0313737/)

6

> [50 Shades of Grey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2322441/)

7

> [The Fifth Element](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/)

8

> [3:10 to Yuma](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381849/)

9

> [(500) Days of Summer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1022603/)

10

> [Air Force One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/) ?

Comment: Air Force One is valid, though I was thinking of another movie.

Comment: I was thinking number 2 is Edge of Tomorrow

Comment: Passenger 57 for 10?

Comment: @derium, That's the one.

Answer (score 2):

getting tired and have some work to do so here are the ones ive got so far

2

> 50 first dates

3

> 127 hours

7

> The Fifth Element

8

> 3:10 to Yuma

9

> 500 days of summer perhaps? (never saw the film)

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 may also be

> Groundhog Day

Number 6:

> Das Parfum. Die Geschichte eines Mörders
>  or Fifty Shades of Grey

Answer (score 2):

The two that are yet to be solved:

4. > Apollo 13
5. > Two weeks' notice (though I'll admit I got that through google)

Answer (score 1):

2:

> 50 first dates

4:

> War of the Worlds (Might be wrong)

7:

> The fifth element

10:

> Non-Stop (Might be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

3:

> 127 Hours

9:

> 500 Days of Summer